# Fuel cell potential cycling: How can I increase the rise time?

Tags: operational-amplifier, electronic-load

First of all, my background on electronics is quite limited.

I conduct potential cycling experiments on fuel cells. I think, in your terms it would be, I drive capacitive loads with a step voltage input.

[image: Figure 1]

In Figure 1, I made a very brief drawing of the cell and electronic load connection. In the right, it is the voltage-current characteristics of a fuel cell. As you can see it is quite exponential between 0.7 and 1 V. Furthermore, at the bottom, very simple equivalent circuit of the fuel cell can be seen. I believe that my problem is related with those capacitors or in electrochemistry terms, electrical double layer.

In the cycling experiments, when the upper voltage is set to 0.9 V, rise time of the voltage increases a lot. I have measured couple of cycling behaviors with an oscilloscope, and it can be seen in Figure 2. I did not calculate rise time here but approximately measured when the voltage reaches and equilibrates at the desired point. When the voltage stepped from lower to higher value, current reverses and rushes. DC load reports current value as 0. Furthermore, there is no problem going from higher voltage to lower voltage, almost immediately it reaches to desired lower voltage.

[image: Figure 2]

Is there something that I can do to improve DC load response? I can add more information and graphs.

Best Regards

Comment: Since I'm no specialist on fuel cells, I'd like to see a published research paper (several, if possible) of something closely related to whatever it is that you are doing. DOI would be fine. Also, I'm *very slow* (and, unfortunately, also don't have a working crystal ball.) So some specific, quantitative idea about what **improve** means to you would be nice to read about. That's just me, of course. Others may have different questions.

Comment: I think you also need to show the specification of your load, the current  rushing and changing could be an effect related to the load, also providing the time distance between your samples would also give some insight to other posters to help you since they can gauge the dimensions of the capacitance you are dealing with and what to expect

Comment: @jonk 

Here are some articles:

1) 10.1149/2.0881807jes
2) 10.1149/2.0651810jes
3) http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jpowsour.2016.05.117
4) 10.1007/s12678-012-0105-2
5) 10.1149/2.083308jes

These are just examples. I read maybe hundreds of articles. Almost no article, I am aware of, actually investigated the real voltage profile. What i want is reducing the rise time when I want to cycle to upper level of 0.9 V. I need to keep rise time similar in all voltage steps e.g. from 0.6 V to 0.9 V should have close rise time with from 0.6 V to 0.9 V. I will add more information when I have time.